# T-SQL Round to nearest Inferior 0.25

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

In SQL server 2008, I would like to get the nearest "0.25", but inferior than the number I put. Preferably with existing functions in 2008.

I need something like this:

```
 0.26 => 0.25 
 0.48 => 0.25
 0.74 => 0.5
 0.98 =>0.75
 25.17 = 25.00
```

I was using `CEILING('number' /0.25) *0.25` but give the nearest superior, and I need the inferior. Any guidance would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Just use floor instead of ceiling? There's probably better solutions too, but that works

Comment: `floor(number * 4) / 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `floor()`, but you also need to get rid of the single quotes around `number`:

```
FLOOR(number / 0.25) * 0.25
```